# Generate random GUID

Tags: primary-key, guid, abap

I want to generate a random `UUID` like in `Java` with `UUID.randomUUID()`.

I came up with the function `GUID_GENERATE` and used it like this

```
    DO 5 TIMES.
       CALL FUNCTION 'GUID_CREATE'
        IMPORTING
         ev_guid_16 = ev_guid_16
         ev_guid_22 = ev_guid_22
         ev_guid_32 = ev_guid_32.

       WRITE: /, ev_guid_16, ev_guid_22, ev_guid_32.
    ENDDO.
```

The result of this program is always the same `GUID`. I need a new random one at every request.

I want to use it as a primary key in database table. This key will be transmitted via a Web Service to a Java application and user there as identifier, too.

Do you have any ideas how I can generate random `UUID/GUID` in `ABAP`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure the created `GUID` is always the same? Because this shouldn't be happening. Note that the difference between them can be just one character when you generate them inside a fast loop.

Comment: It was one single character... Stupid! Thank you for that hint!

Answer (score 10):

First of all you are using a function module that is obsolete. The comment at the beginning of the source code states that.

```
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
* NOW this function has been replaced, see note 935047      "BINK215094
* 28.6.2006 The function module has been switched to the new UUID methods
*           which exist in the class cl_system_uuid
*           - due to compatibility reasons we catch the exceptions
*           - sy-subrc not touched manually
*             (sy-subrc was set in case of an error when calling the former
*             'RFCControl' kernel-call, but it wasn't evaluated and finally
*             overwritten when leaving this function)
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please use class `CL_SYSTEM_UUID` and the following methods:

```
IF_SYSTEM_UUID_STATIC~CREATE_UUID_X16
IF_SYSTEM_UUID_STATIC~CREATE_UUID_C22
IF_SYSTEM_UUID_STATIC~CREATE_UUID_C26
IF_SYSTEM_UUID_STATIC~CREATE_UUID_C32
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try them and report if they work. If so I guess you earned the green arrow :-)